# Filter using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I need to filter the JSON above using Underscore.js

How can I return just the items that "Balance" is different from 0

```js
{
 Currency: 'BCC',
 Balance: 0,
 Available: 0,
 Pending: 0,
 CryptoAddress: null
}, {
 Currency: 'BLOCK',
 Balance: 0,
 Available: 0,
 Pending: 0,
 CryptoAddress: 'Bd24akqYDG97k6xmUqsnxAtrBRoXeffQhx'
}, {
 Currency: 'BTC',
 Balance: 0.00153928,
 Available: 0.00153928,
 Pending: 0,
 CryptoAddress: '1BgWkjF1mwe1MZoCvxMmfSJ6fppNMD5GSx'
}, {
 Currency: 'BTG',
 Balance: 2e-8,
 Available: 2e-8,
 Pending: 0,
 CryptoAddress: null
}
```

Comment: What is your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
_.filter(yourList, function(obj){
   return obj.Balance !== 0
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a codepen example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbMRKY?editors=1111

```
let filtered = _.filter(transactions, (transaction) => {
 return transaction.Balance !== 0;
})
```